# Dislocation Jogs and kinks

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, topological-defects

When two dislocations interact, it creates a step which is known as jogs (if it is from two different slip planes) or kinks (if it is in the same slip plane). My confusion is, why it is like a step? How this step is formed? If two lines intersect, it meets at a point. So how the concept of step comes in there?

Will be really grateful if someone helps me visualize the whole picture.

Comment: https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Materials_Science/TLP_Library_II/7%3A_Mechanisms_of_Plasticity/7.6%3A_Dislocation_Intersections_to_Form_Jogs_and_Kinks may help.

Comment: Such steps occur because the dislocation segment on the stressed side continues to move, while the rest is pinned. Metallurgy texts such as Dieter typically review this in detail.

Comment: Thank you @JonCuster for the link

Comment: I will check the book @Chemomechanics. Thank you so much for the recommendation.